# Creating time scale in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I have the following data:

```
   parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse,
   format = d3.time.format("%Y");

  var myData = [
   { dataField: "A", coords: [
    {xCoord: parseDate('1990') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1991') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1992') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1993') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1994') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1995') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1996') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1997') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1998') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1999') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100}
    ]
  },
  { dataField: "B",coords: [
    {xCoord: parseDate('1990') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1991') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1992') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1993') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1994') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1995') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1996') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1997') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1998') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100},
    {xCoord: parseDate('1999') , yCoord: Math.random() * 100}
    ]
  }
```

and I am trying to create a line graph using d3.  Additionally, I have the code:

```
    var data = function (d) { return d.coords; };
    var xValue = function (d) { return d.xCoord; };
    var yValue = function (d) { return d.yCoord; };
```

I have been creating my scale as such:

```
    xScale = d3.time.scale()
      .domain([new Date(1988,10,30),new Date(2000,01,30)])
      .range([margin.left, 600 - margin.right]);
```

However, my goal is to have my domain adjust itself to be the smallest year to the largest year (or mabye even extending an extra year in each direction).  But so far, I have been unsuccessful. I have attempted to use

```
    .domain(d3.extent(data, xValue));
```

But haven't had luck.  I'm fairly new to javascript and think my struggles lie within the way I stored my data.  Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in d3.extent function to get the min and max of an array. It takes an an array and an optional accessor function. It will return an array of 2 values, the min and max:

`[min, max]`

I would try

`xScale.domain(d3.extent(myData[0].coords, function(d) {return d.xCoord; }));`

and then rinse and repeat for the other data labels You could do it in a `for` loop if there are a bunch of different data sets.

Comment: I would say that the way you stored your data could be improved. If all the dates are the same for each field, it'd be best to have `{date: 1999, A: someNumber, B: someNumber, etc}`

Comment: Thanks @elsherbini , it's actually just mock data that will be replaced by the back end later on.  The extent is creating a mess of different errors, is their a simple way to loop through the array with JSON elements and just find the max that way? It's not exactly ideal, but I just need this mock data to work in the prototype.

Comment: hmm, the code above is working for me here: http://tributary.io/inlet/5776547 I am just writing the domain and range to the svg element. I began to try to build a simple line chart with it, but I have to run. You can check out the beginnings of the line chart code in the commented block.